# How to add Material UI V5 ThemeProvider in Storybook V6 in NX

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, storybook, nx.dev

I am currently using `nx.dev` as a `monorepo`. I have multiple react clients.
Thanks to NX I have a central `Material Ui` Configuration (inside the lib folder).

I'm trying to use `Storybook` inside that mui folder. Unfortunately, the `ThemeProvider` does not intervene. That means my custom palette etc. Will not be taken over. Unfortunately, I don't know why `Storybook` is not accepting the `Themeprovider` from `MUI`. Is it because of NX? Or does this have nothing to do with it?

I think there are some issues between `react 18`, `Storybook 6` and `MUI 5`.
But there must be a solution, cause I already build it successful, without NX and lower versions.
Need help please!

Inside my lib folder there is a mui folder with a .storybook folder.

main.js

```
const rootMain = require('../../../.storybook/main');

module.exports = {
  ...rootMain,

  core: { ...rootMain.core, builder: 'webpack5' },

  stories: [
    ...rootMain.stories,
    '../src/lib/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../src/lib/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [
    ...rootMain.addons,
    '@nrwl/react/plugins/storybook',
   
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // apply any global webpack configs that might have been specified in .storybook/main.js
    if (rootMain.webpackFinal) {
      config = await rootMain.webpackFinal(config, { configType });
    }

    // add your own webpack tweaks if needed

    return config;
  },
};
```

preview.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, theme } from '../src';


export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
};

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Story />
    </ThemeProvider>
  ),
];
```

I als tried that in preview.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react'
import { ThemeProvider } from '../src'
import { theme } from '../src'


export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}

addDecorator((story) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    {story()}
  </ThemeProvider>
))
```

in the src folder of the lib folder folder there is an index.ts file containing

```
export * from './theme';

export * from '@mui/material';
```

theme.ts

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette,
  spacing: [0, 4, 8, 16, 24, 32, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96],
  components: {
    ...Buttons,
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that issue

[react material-ui v5 theming doesnt work with storybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422566/react-material-ui-v5-theming-doesnt-work-with-storybook).

That helped me a lot.

```
import { ThemeProvider, theme } from '../src';
import { ThemeProvider as Emotion10ThemeProvider } from 'emotion-theming';

export const decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <Emotion10ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Story />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Emotion10ThemeProvider>
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

@maxfromgermany.
I had such a problem recently and solved with this codebase. Add the following code to the ".storybook/preview.js".

```
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/
    }
  }
}

import React from "react"

import { addDecorator } from "@storybook/react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles"

import { muiTheme } from "../src/config/mui-theme"

addDecorator((story) => <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>{story()}</ThemeProvider>)
```

~ Storm In Talent